# Highcharts - Plot a double donut chart on drilldown level

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts, donut-chart

I plotted a double donut chart using Highcharts library. My requirement is when I drill down from the initial level, I should be able to plot another double donut chart.
For eg: This is the initial level. Now if I click on Email, it should drill down and show another double donut chart
[image: Initial level]

This is the desired result after drill down
[image: Something like this]

Following is the current code to render chart. For each series data, we have drilldown option which can take a string for eg: 'Email'. I need double donut under the drilldown but drilldown series with same id don't work and I end up getting only 1 donut chart.

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    type: 'pie',
    /* backgroundColor: '#000', */
  },
  title: {
    text: '',
  },
  subtitle: {
    text: '',
  },

  accessibility: {
    announceNewData: {
      enabled: true,
    },
    point: {
      valueSuffix: '%',
    },
  },

  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: true,
        format: '{point.name}: {point.y:.1f}%',
      },
    },
  },

  tooltip: {
    headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:11px">{series.name}</span><br>',
    pointFormat:
      '<span style="color:{point.color}">{point.name}</span>: <b>{point.y:.2f}%</b> of total<br/>',
  },

  series: [
    {
      innerSize: 150,
      size: 200,
      name: 'Browsers',
      colorByPoint: true,
      data: [
        {
          name: 'Email',
          y: 62.74,
          drilldown: 'Email',
        },
        {
          name: 'Social Media',
          y: 10.57,
          drilldown: 'Social Media',
        },
        {
          name: 'Shopping',
          y: 7.23,
          drilldown: 'Shopping',
        },
        {
          name: 'Trading',
          y: 5.58,
          drilldown: 'Trading',
        },
        {
          name: 'Others',
          y: 4.02,
          drilldown: 'null',
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      showInLegend: false,
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: false,
      },
      innerSize: 100,
      size: 150,
      name: 'Email',
      colorByPoint: true,
      data: [
        {
          name: 'Email',
          y: 52.74,
          drilldown: null,
        },
        {
          name: 'Social Media',
          y: 15.57,
          drilldown: null,
        },
        {
          name: 'Shopping',
          y: 12.23,
          drilldown: null,
        },
        {
          name: 'Trading',
          y: 5.58,
          drilldown: null,
        },
        {
          name: 'Other',
          y: 4.02,
          drilldown: null,
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
  drilldown: {
    series: [
      {
        innerSize: 150,
        size: 200,
        name: 'Email',
        id: 'Email',
        data: [
          ['Gsuite', 0.1],
          ['office365', 1.3],
          ['Yahoo', 53.02],
        ],
      },
      {
        innerSize: 100,
        size: 150,
        name: 'Email',
        id: 'Email',
        data: [
          ['user1', 0.1],
          ['user2', 1.3],
          ['user3', 53.02],
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
});
```

This is the current result
[image: This is the current result]

Here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3wyh879L/5/) which I am currently working on.

Any help on this will be much appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: https://observablehq.com/@d3/zoomable-sunburst

Comment: Have you considered using the sunburst series? https://www.highcharts.com/demo/sunburst

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I will take a look at sunburst examples. I will let you know if it solves my problem. Thanks